# Reseeding identity column in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have to reseed a table in my staging database, based on the `Max(ID)` from a table in my destination database.

So, I created a query that does a `SELECT MAX(ID) AS MaxID From Tablename`, and that went into the resultset and named the ResultName as maxID. (An Execute SQL component).

I then created a second Execute SQL component, and mapped the parameter from the previous component to a parameter called MaxID (Parameter size: 0, Data Type: Decimal).

The SQL statement for the 2nd component is:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (Person, RESEED, ?)
```

I am receiving the following error:

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "DBCC CHECKIDENT
>   (Person, RESEED, ?)" failed with the following error: "The type for
>   parameter '@P1' cannot be deduced in this context.". Possible failure
>   reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set
>   correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established
>   correctly.

Any guidance or assistance would be great.

edit:
I am trying to use the following SQL in my Execute SQL task:

```
DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(100) = 'DBCC CHECKIDENT (Person, RESEED, ' + CAST(100 AS VARCHAR) + ')'
EXEC (@Sql)
```

But getting an error:

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "DECLARE @Sql
>   VARCHAR(100) = 'DBCC CHECKIDENT (Pers..." failed with the following
>   error: "Parameter name is unrecognized.". Possible failure reasons:
>   Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly,
>   parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Comment: use an _expression_ to set the sql value

Comment: But be careful... there's many reasons that the ID's in the target won't be synchronised with the source. You should probably use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF` instead.

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid - I'm unsure how to use the expression on the 'Execute SQL' task. I see there is an expressions property - but not sure how I can set the SQL command from there, and use the value from my previously executed "Select Max..." component.

Comment: Click on the expression property to open the editor. Then you can type something like `"DBCC CHECKIDENT (Person, RESEED," + ((DT_WSTR,20) @[User::YourVariable]) + ")"` and put that against the SQL property. The expression is evaluated. There are two tricks: 1. The variable should be of type int, not object; 2. You now need to cast it from int to string (thats what `DT_WSTR` does)

Answer (score -3):

Try to construct the sql query and execute it with dynamic sql

Comment: I just tried that now, but get an error. I've modified the question to include this.